# Permission denied, please try again

Tags: ssh, remote-access

I'm trying to connect to another computer in my house via ssh.
Both computers have ubuntu and openssh installed. When I run the command "ssh username@ip" on terminal I'm asked for the user's password I'm trying to connect to. I type it but I get this error "Permission denied, please try again." I'm sure the password is correct, then why can't I access?

Comment: You wrote "When I run the command username@ip" -- is that really the command you use? Do you mean `ssh username@ip`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may have more reasons.
What comes to my mind as first is :

1. You are trying to log as root (Ubuntu does not allow it)
2. On target machine, there is not allowed logging with password (can be configured in /etc/ssh/sshd.conf)
3. You entered wrong IP (of wrong computer)
4. Key authorization is required (Also can be edited in /etc/ssh/sshd.conf)

And as Elias said, if you are  using  `user@ip` and not `ssh user@ip`, it is obvious that it is not working.

Comment: I was entering wrong IP of wrong computer.

Comment: regarding point 2: can be configured in /etc/ssh/sshd.conf of the local machine or target machine?

Comment: target machine.